# What version of dropwizard-hibernate supports try with resources?

Tags: hibernate, dropwizard, autocloseable

I am aware that the `try with resources` feature is available from Java 7 onwards, I was hoping the later versions of dropwizard hibernate would provide a Sessions object that implement the `autocloseable` interface.

I wasnt able to see that in the javadocs for any version of dropwizard. Is there a way to figure out the version if it does spport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should be fine with DW 1.0.0 and upwards.

Hibernate Session in Version 5.1.0 is Autocloseable. According to the release notes, this made it in in 1.0.0.

http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.5/docs/about/release-notes.html

Cheers,

Artur